# is there an equivalent to "snoop -a" on linux?

Tags: linux

Sun's snoop command provides the -a option so you can "listen" to packets on your audio device.  Do any linux packet sniffing tools provide equivalent functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hacky but could you use tcpdump and push stdout straight into your speakers?

`sudo tcpdump -vvvv | padsp tee | aplay`

- **tcpdump** - linux for snoop
- **padsp** - PulseAudio OSS Wrapper
- **aplay** - command-line sound recorder and player for ALSA soundcard driver

Comment: going to accept as it's looking like this is as close as you can get on linux (no 1:1 equivalent)